# UIScrollView gets created at wrong position for first time

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a scroll view which goes behind of navigation controlled but when the view controller is viewed at the first time scrollview gets created below UINavigation Bar if you scroll it gives a leg and gets adjusted and works fine. I check everything but I didn't found the problem I think it's a Bug

**It's Little bit difficult to notice in GIF. I Have [Attached a project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2csGr9uKp1DV2I3T3EtWllMbTA) creating that problem just have a look at it. It's attached below**

[image]

[LINK TO PROJECT](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2csGr9uKp1DV2I3T3EtWllMbTA)

Comment: From the storyboard select your controller > in Attribute Inspector disable Adjust Scroll View Insets Also check if you have set any contentInset.

Comment: @BharatModi i worked Thanks :)

Comment: @BharatModi Can you explain me why it happen.

Comment: UIViewControllers in iOS7 and above have a setting called automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets. If this is YES, the scroll view's insets will automatically be adjusted according to the height of the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved unchecking Adjust Scroll View Insets as shown below. This stops your scroll view from ignoring you auto layout constraints and stops it from adjusting its bounds from your navigation bar.

[image]